# Animation doesn't play

Tags: animation

So, I've been working on an animation for quite some time now, and pressing space/clicking play to play the animation has always been working. But now, out of nowhere, when I click space or play it doesn't do anything. The FPS counter starts to jump but the "current frame" counter remains at zero. It also kicks me back to the very start of the animation every time I try to play, despite being somewhere else on the timeline.. To be clear, there is no play issue with any other file.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?
Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPgiK.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you're in the camera view?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. It should also play even if I'm not in the camera view. @deltaray

Comment: Yes, but without knowing what your animation does, maybe you were expecting to see camera movement.  For instance, if only the camera was moving, you might think the animation wasn't playing.

Comment: Well, not only the camera but parts of the model itself, but when I hit play the frame number just instantly goes to zero and stays there, but the FPS counter is going. Nothing that's supposed to move moves. I'm afraid I've activated some sort of setting, but no clue what it could be. @deltaray